# When trying to install Magento sample data I get errors

Tags: magento-1.9, database

I have created a brand new database and I am trying to import the data from the sample data. When I import I get this-

```
Static analysis:

214 errors were found during analysis.

Ending quote ' was expected. (near "" at position 709240)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "UNLOCK" at position 56679)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "LOCK" at position 57631)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "UNLOCK" at position 57788)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "LOCK" at position 58644)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "UNLOCK" at position 58903)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "LOCK" at position 59879)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "UNLOCK" at position 60021)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "LOCK" at position 61008)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "UNLOCK" at position 61150)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "LOCK" at position 61777)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "UNLOCK" at position 61910)
A comma or a closing bracket was expected. (near "'Parent role id'" at position 62272)
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "5" at position 62314)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "unsigned" at position 62317)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "LOCK" at position 62985)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "UNLOCK" at position 63112)
A comma or a closing bracket was expected. (near "'Api role Id'" at position 63476)
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "255" at position 63515)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "DEFAULT" at position 63520)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "LOCK" at position 64293)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "UNLOCK" at position 64420)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "LOCK" at position 65285)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "UNLOCK" at position 65421)
A comma or a closing bracket was expected. (near "'Quantity of log ins'" at position 66268)
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "6" at position 66320)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "NOT NULL" at position 66323)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "LOCK" at position 66631)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "UNLOCK" at position 66758)
A comma or a closing bracket was expected. (near "'Count'" at position 67147)
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "`type`" at position 67237)
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "`value`" at position 67244)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "ENGINE" at position 67255)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "LOCK" at position 67427)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "UNLOCK" at position 67563)
A comma or a closing bracket was expected. (near "'Category ID'" at position 67942)
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "255" at position 67974)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "DEFAULT" at position 67979)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "LOCK" at position 68400)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "UNLOCK" at position 68614)
A comma or a closing bracket was expected. (near "'Category ID'" at position 68993)
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "255" at position 69025)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "DEFAULT" at position 69030)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "LOCK" at position 69450)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "UNLOCK" at position 69664)
A comma or a closing bracket was expected. (near "'Category ID'" at position 70049)
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "10" at position 70083)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "unsigned" at position 70087)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "LOCK" at position 70537)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "UNLOCK" at position 70757)
A comma or a closing bracket was expected. (near "'Category ID'" at position 71142)
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "10" at position 71176)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "unsigned" at position 71180)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "LOCK" at position 71629)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "UNLOCK" at position 71849)
A comma or a closing bracket was expected. (near "'Entity Type ID'" at position 72269)
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "5" at position 72317)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "unsigned" at position 72320)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "LOCK" at position 73175)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "UNLOCK" at position 75445)
A comma or a closing bracket was expected. (near "'Entity Type ID'" at position 75881)
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "5" at position 75925)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "unsigned" at position 75928)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "LOCK" at position 77332)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "UNLOCK" at position 78688)
A comma or a closing bracket was expected. (near "'Entity Type ID'" at position 79121)
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "5" at position 79165)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "unsigned" at position 79168)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "LOCK" at position 80564)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "UNLOCK" at position 81359)
A comma or a closing bracket was expected. (near "'Entity Type ID'" at position 81780)
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "5" at position 81824)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "unsigned" at position 81827)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "LOCK" at position 83198)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "UNLOCK" at position 86438)
A comma or a closing bracket was expected. (near "'Entity Type ID'" at position 86862)
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "5" at position 86906)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "unsigned" at position 86909)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "LOCK" at position 88269)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "UNLOCK" at position 91472)
A comma or a closing bracket was expected. (near "'Entity Type ID'" at position 91905)
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "5" at position 91949)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "unsigned" at position 91952)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "LOCK" at position 93352)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "UNLOCK" at position 100806)
A comma or a closing bracket was expected. (near "'parent_id'" at position 101220)
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "255" at position 101380)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "NOT NULL" at position 101385)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "LOCK" at position 104132)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "UNLOCK" at position 111287)
A comma or a closing bracket was expected. (near "'parent_id'" at position 111701)
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "255" at position 111861)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "NOT NULL" at position 111866)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "LOCK" at position 114613)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "UNLOCK" at position 121768)
A comma or a closing bracket was expected. (near "'parent_id'" at position 122182)
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "255" at position 122342)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "NOT NULL" at position 122347)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "LOCK" at position 125094)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "UNLOCK" at position 132249)
A comma or a closing bracket was expected. (near "'parent_id'" at position 132663)
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "255" at position 132823)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "NOT NULL" at position 132828)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "LOCK" at position 135575)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "UNLOCK" at position 135765)
A comma or a closing bracket was expected. (near "'Category ID'" at position 136105)
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "10" at position 136139)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "unsigned" at position 136143)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "LOCK" at position 136922)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "UNLOCK" at position 140111)
A comma or a closing bracket was expected. (near "'Category ID'" at position 140469)
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "10" at position 140503)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "unsigned" at position 140507)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "LOCK" at position 141847)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "UNLOCK" at position 186322)
A comma or a closing bracket was expected. (near "'Product ID'" at position 186706)
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "10" at position 186739)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "unsigned" at position 186743)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "LOCK" at position 187113)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "UNLOCK" at position 187333)
A comma or a closing bracket was expected. (near "'Product ID'" at position 187717)
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "10" at position 187750)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "unsigned" at position 187754)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "LOCK" at position 188123)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "UNLOCK" at position 188343)
A comma or a closing bracket was expected. (near "'Category ID'" at position 188713)
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "10" at position 188747)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "unsigned" at position 188751)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "LOCK" at position 189402)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "UNLOCK" at position 189607)
A comma or a closing bracket was expected. (near "'Visitor ID'" at position 190030)
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "10" at position 190064)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "unsigned" at position 190068)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "LOCK" at position 191374)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "UNLOCK" at position 192695)
A comma or a closing bracket was expected. (near "'Is Searchable'" at position 193348)
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "5" at position 193392)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "unsigned" at position 193395)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "LOCK" at position 195335)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "UNLOCK" at position 204313)
A comma or a closing bracket was expected. (near "'Required'" at position 204806)
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "10" at position 204835)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "unsigned" at position 204839)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "LOCK" at position 205433)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "UNLOCK" at position 205851)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "LOCK" at position 206961)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "UNLOCK" at position 207408)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "LOCK" at position 209025)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "UNLOCK" at position 209230)
A comma or a closing bracket was expected. (near "'Position'" at position 209874)
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "5" at position 209910)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "unsigned" at position 209913)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "LOCK" at position 211105)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "UNLOCK" at position 211968)
A comma or a closing bracket was expected. (near "'Selection Price Type'" at position 212497)
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "12" at position 212555)
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "4" at position 212558)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "NOT NULL" at position 212561)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "LOCK" at position 213313)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "UNLOCK" at position 213530)
A comma or a closing bracket was expected. (near "'Option Id'" at position 214089)
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "6" at position 214128)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "DEFAULT" at position 214131)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "LOCK" at position 214442)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "UNLOCK" at position 214647)
A comma or a closing bracket was expected. (near "'Product ID'" at position 215001)
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "5" at position 215037)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "unsigned" at position 215040)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "LOCK" at position 215840)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "UNLOCK" at position 217192)
A comma or a closing bracket was expected. (near "'Entity Type ID'" at position 217609)
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "5" at position 217657)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "unsigned" at position 217660)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "LOCK" at position 218934)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "UNLOCK" at position 266131)
A comma or a closing bracket was expected. (near "'Entity Type ID'" at position 266564)
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "5" at position 266608)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "unsigned" at position 266611)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "LOCK" at position 267976)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "UNLOCK" at position 344472)
A comma or a closing bracket was expected. (near "'Entity Type ID'" at position 344902)
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "5" at position 344946)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "unsigned" at position 344949)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "LOCK" at position 346307)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "UNLOCK" at position 416642)
A comma or a closing bracket was expected. (near "'Entity Type ID'" at position 417072)
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "5" at position 417116)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "unsigned" at position 417119)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "LOCK" at position 418547)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "UNLOCK" at position 418740)
A comma or a closing bracket was expected. (near "'Entity ID'" at position 419173)
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "5" at position 419210)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "unsigned" at position 419213)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "LOCK" at position 420641)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "UNLOCK" at position 420846)
A comma or a closing bracket was expected. (near "'Entity Type ID'" at position 421260)
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "5" at position 421304)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "unsigned" at position 421307)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "LOCK" at position 422656)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "UNLOCK" at position 577057)
A comma or a closing bracket was expected. (near "'Attribute ID'" at position 577512)
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "10" at position 577546)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "unsigned" at position 577550)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "LOCK" at position 578442)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "UNLOCK" at position 622307)
A comma or a closing bracket was expected. (near "'Value ID'" at position 622698)
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "5" at position 622732)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "unsigned" at position 622735)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "LOCK" at position 623705)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "UNLOCK" at position 646807)
A comma or a closing bracket was expected. (near "'Entity Type ID'" at position 647224)
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "5" at position 647268)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "unsigned" at position 647271)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "LOCK" at position 648608)
```

I am working with the latest version of WAMP. I tried both compressed and uncompressed, I also have tried it with partial import unchecked. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up importing the exact same database through command line with no issues. If anyone knows why that would work but not through phpmyadmin I would be curious.